# Wordpress Custom JS Location

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

We decided to go to another provider and rebuild the website. Accidently, we moved the old domain as well and we can't access the wordpress backend nor the frontend anymor. Now for the new page, I need a Custom javascript code I entered on a specific page with **Elementor**. Where can I find my old code now without accessing the homepage? I have FTP and Database access.

Comment: If you have access to your database and FTP, you can make a backup of files and data and restore in your new domain. When you have all, in this page (for example) explains how you make a restore of files and database: https://blogvault.net/manually-restoring-wordpress-site/

Comment: Sadly, the new page is already progressing so we would have to delete everything again which is not an option.

Comment: Ups... then I think you must download all files from FTP and search file by file. Anywise, why you need code in a Wordpress page? If you wrote manual code, it will be in the custom code folder, here you have some indications: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-custom-code-to-wordpress/

Comment: Yeah what I need is the location of the custom javascript which is entered inside Elementor, just a small but powerful code snipped which does an ajax request and it would take long to reproduce

Comment: Ok, usually Wordpress save all .js files on the folder /wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/js/. Look there, luck!

Answer (score 1):

Where do you put the code? Depending on the answer you need to look at different locations.
Afaik elementor doesn't support custom js nativly. You can bypass that with a html widget or custom plugin. If you used elementors gui for that it's probably stored like all other elementor related content inside wp_post_meta of your database.

If you don't know the page where it was used I would suggest to export the database as sql and use an editor to search for a text string related to the code (for example the url of the ajax request).

If you know the page you can do the same but faster. Look for the id of the post with the code, search for it in wp_post_meta and go on like mentioned before.

If you havn't used elementors gui the script could lie inside a directory on the server probably inside your theme.